# Node v6 failing on object spread

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I had a question about why node v6.7 would be failing to run this code:

```
var a = {
    foo: 'bar'
}

var b = {
    ...a,
    my: 'sharona'
}
console.log(b)
```

Anyone have an idea why that would be? I thought v6 supported object spreading..? But I guess not? Here is the error I'm seeing:

```
/home/teselagen/ve/tnrtest.js:6
    ...a,
    ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Comment: Works in Node 8 with --harmony flag.

Comment: Works in node 8.3.0 even without flag

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Looks like ES6 spread operator only works for arrays and iterables. It is specifically designed to **NOT WORK** for objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Relevant quote:

> Only apply for iterables
>
> ```
> var obj = {"key1":"value1"};
> function myFunction(x) {
>     console.log(x); // undefined
> }
> myFunction(...obj);
> var args = [...obj];
> console.log(args, args.length) //[] 0
> ```

Though the MDN article previously suggested that trying to use the spread operator on objects should result in undefined instead of throwing an error. As of [this revision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator$revision/1254317), the current MDN article discusses support for "Spread for object literals"

Additionally the node.js compatibility table claims node.js fully comply with the specification of the spread operator with arrays and iterables, but specifically indicates that object rest/spread properties are not supported: http://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--object-rest-spread-properties, at least not until Node version 8.60 (at which point the color turns green to indicate that beginning in 8.3, Node *does* support the object spread/rest operator, [as pointed out in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40066910/1175496))

Comment: I think they were using object spread thru  `--harmony_destructuring` flag in previous versions, but removed it because it "isn't in standard". It was very useful to fast prototype instead of using Babel for everything... :-(

Comment: This is now out of date. Object spread does work in modern browsers, and is in Node 8

Answer (score 59):

Using rest/spread with objects is a separate proposal, which you can read about [here](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread). A proposal doesn't get accepted for the yearly ES release unless it reaches stage 4, and it is currently stage 3. It may make it into ES2018. If you want to use it now, you'll have to use a transpiler like `babel`.

---

**EDIT:** As of Node v8.3, object rest/spread is available without the need for any transpilation.

Comment: I have node 8.6 and still have the problem

Comment: Are you sure you're on 8.6? Try adding `console.log(process.version)` to the top of your script to make sure that it is running that version. If so, there is probable some other issue in your code.