# Push partial result data in array and send

Tags: mysql, node-mysql

I have a MySQL table in which a column name is `tags` and type is `VARCHAR`. I'm inserting the data with comma separated:

```
tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6
```

My query from node is:

```
app.get('/tagtest', (req, res) => {

    var tags = [];       // <= Not sure if I need this or how to push tags here.

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM tagtestpost", (err, rows)=>{
        res.send(rows)
    });

});
```

Response from above query is:

```
[{"id":1,"tags":"tag1, tag2, tag3"},{"id":2,"tags":"tag2, tag4"}]
```

I want to return the tags in an array. So the `response` should look like:

```
[{"id":1,"tags":[tag1, tag2, tag3]},{"id":2,"tags":[tag2, tag4]}]
```

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE1**

```
app.get('/showtagposts', (req, res) => {

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM postwithtagtest", (err, rows)=>{

        var a = rows;

    const expected = a.map((post) => ({
        ...post,
        tags: post.tags.split(/,\s+/)
    }));

    console.log(expected);

            res.json(expected);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer doesn't actually split the tags into separate values within an array. The following does:

```js
    const a = [{"id":1,"tags":"tag1, tag2, tag3"},{"id":2,"tags":"tag2, tag4"}];

    // ES6
    const expected = a.map((post) => ({
        ...post,
        tags: post.tags.split(/,\s+/)
    }));

    // ES5
    const expected = a.map(function (post) {
        return Object.assign({}, post, {
            tags: post.tags.split(/,\s+/)
        });
    });

    console.log(expected);
```

**Update**

It appears that the spread operator does not work with object when using Node. See here: [Node v6 failing on object spread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066731/node-v6-failing-on-object-spread)

I've changed it to use `Object.assign` instead.

```
app.get('/showtagposts', (req, res) => {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM postwithtagtest", (err, rows) => {
        const data = rows.map((post) => {
            return Object.assign({}, post, {
                tags: post.tags.split(/,\s+/)
            });
        });

        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: ...post,
        ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

Getting this error when applying it in nodejs

Comment: The snippet runs for me. And you're using ES6, right?

Comment: Did you copy what I posted? Including the extra `()` wrapping the return value?

Comment: I did. Please check **UPDATE1** in the question. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not **MySQL** way to achieve what you wanted. I have a **JS** way to achieve what you need.

```js
    var a = [{"id":1,"tags":"tag1, tag2, tag3"},{"id":2,"tags":"tag2, tag4"}];
    var expected =[];
    a.forEach( function (eachObj){
        var obj = {};
        for (var key in eachObj) {
            if (eachObj.hasOwnProperty(key) && key ==='tags'){
                obj[key] = [eachObj[key]];
            }else{
                obj[key] = eachObj[key];
            }
        }
        expected.push(obj);
    });

    console.log(expected);
```

Comment: That works! One question. The quotes inside of the array. Is that ok?

Comment: I think so, it should be Ok.