# Mocha and ES6, Unexpected token (spread operator)

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

i need your help.
I need write unit tests for my project (we use mocha and nyc for running tests)
I get an error when I run mocha

```
const payload = { ...obj, vitality };
                      ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/linx/multichannel/optout/test/unit/controller/version.test.js:5:20)
```

This is my function

```
   const checkVitality = (req,res, obj, uuid) => {
      const vitality = Object.values(obj).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator && currentValue ,true);
      const payload = { ...obj, vitality }; // <=======Syntax error
      logger.debug(`vitality check request`, uuid,100, payload);
      return payload;
   };
```

If I run the code, the function is compiled, but if i run test i got this error.I tried to connect BABEL but still got this error
Thankful!

Comment: What does your `obj` object contain?

Comment: Which version of node are you using ? Are you sure the object spread operator is available in your node version ?

Comment: Otherwise you will have to use `babel` and install the babel plugin `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`

Comment: @Ethane { userdata: true, mc: true, vitality: true }

Comment: @Dimitri node version v8.1.2 , yep i sure it is work if i run my server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40066910/314862

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that JavaScript's [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is not yet part of the official spec. Therefore, you need to use some sort of transpiler like [`babel`](http://babeljs.io).

There are a few ways to deal with this issue, but I recommend requiring `@babel/register` in your `npm` script.

You must first install the dependency by running:

```
npm install @babel/core --save-dev
npm install @babel/register --save-dev
```

Then add the following to your `package.json`

```
{
   //...
   "scripts": {
      "test": "mocha --require @babel/register ./test/**/*.js"
   }
   //...
}
```