# SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I am trying to deploy my code on heroku and it give me Error.

Provide me the solution.
It show unexpected token ... which i cannot resolve.
i am using mongo atlas online database link to connect to database.
For more clearity i am adding my git repository
github.com/laxitnahar/temp

ERROR:-

````
2022-08-05T11:57:48.831721+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-05T11:57:51.114009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-08-05T11:57:52.585567+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-05T11:57:52.585595+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start /app
2022-08-05T11:57:52.585596+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2022-08-05T11:57:52.585596+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-05T11:57:52.809406+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/build/main/lib/MongoStore.js:75
2022-08-05T11:57:52.809420+00:00 app[web.1]: constructor({ collectionName = 'sessions', ttl = 1209600, mongoOptions = {}, autoRemove = 'native', autoRemoveInterval = 10, touchAfter = 0, stringify = true, crypto, ...required }) {
2022-08-05T11:57:52.809423+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^
2022-08-05T11:57:52.809423+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
2022-08-05T11:57:52.809423+00:00 app[web.1]: at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
2022-08-05T11:57:52.809423+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
2022-08-05T11:57:52.809424+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
2022-08-05T11:57:52.809424+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2022-08-05T11:57:52.809424+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2022-08-05T11:57:52.809424+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2022-08-05T11:57:52.809425+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2022-08-05T11:57:52.809425+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2022-08-05T11:57:52.809425+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2022-08-05T11:57:52.815363+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/build/main/index.js:5:38)
2022-08-05T11:57:52.822611+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2022-08-05T11:57:52.822966+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2022-08-05T11:57:52.826142+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2022-08-05T11:57:52.826182+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2022-08-05T11:57:52.826329+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-08-05T11:57:52.826388+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 start script.
2022-08-05T11:57:52.826457+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm```


MongoStore.js


```class MongoStore extends session.Store {
    constructor({ collectionName = 'sessions', ttl = 1209600, mongoOptions = {}, autoRemove = 'native', autoRemoveInterval = 10, touchAfter = 0, stringify = true, crypto, ...required }) {
        super();
        this.crypto = null;
        debug('create MongoStore instance');
        const options = {
            collectionName,
            ttl,
            mongoOptions,
            autoRemove,
            autoRemoveInterval,
            touchAfter,
            stringify,
            crypto: {
                ...{
                    secret: false,
                    algorithm: 'aes-256-gcm',
                    hashing: 'sha512',
                    encodeas: 'base64',
                    key_size: 32,
                    iv_size: 16,
                    at_size: 16,
                },
                ...crypto,
            },
            ...required,
        };```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocha and ES6, Unexpected token (spread operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325061/mocha-and-es6-unexpected-token-spread-operator)

Answer (score 0):

I think It's because you forgot to write two curly brackets ***}*** at the end of your program.
This kind of errors usually happens when you forgot to write a bracket or curly brackets.

Comment: i have already added