# NodeJS problem with spread operators (unexprected token)

Tags: node.js

I've been searching a solution for a while, but nothing seems to work.

I've read in an old article ([Node v6 failing on object spread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066731/node-v6-failing-on-object-spread)) that this issue has been solve as of node v8.3, but it doesn't seems to work for me.

I have a problem with Nodejs (v10.15.3) and spread operators. In fact, whenever I try to use them, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/gabriele/models/Project.js: Unexpected token (15:8)
  13 |       return {
  14 |         id: res.insertId,
> 15 |         ...newProject
     |         ^
  16 |       };
  17 |     } catch ({ sqlMessage }) {
  18 |       console.log(sqlMessage);
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/Users/gabriele/Websites/pages-api/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/gabriele/Websites/pages-api/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdentifier (/Users/gabriele/Websites/pages-api/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4332:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parsePropertyName (/Users/gabriele/Websites/pages-api/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4156:96)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseObj (/Users/gabriele/Websites/pages-api/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4045:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/gabriele/Websites/pages-api/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3719:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/gabriele/Websites/pages-api/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3494:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/gabriele/Websites/pages-api/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3474:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/Users/gabriele/Websites/pages-api/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3404:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/gabriele/Websites/pages-api/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3381:19)
```

This is my code:

```js
...
return {
  id: res.insertId,
  ...newProject

};
...
```

Here is the output if I `console.log(newProject)`:

```
{ name: 'My test', slug: 'my-test', user_id: 1 }
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I just checked and looks like this works in my node 10 environment. Please check the type of newProject. That could be a catch.

Comment: That doesn't look like an error thrown by Node.js, but by something like `eslint`.

Comment: This does not make any sense, ...newProject spread operator is used to accept parameters as an array. What are you trying to do here? Can you post `newProject` init in your code or anything that might help

Comment: @klvenky just updated the code with more info about the error and the output of the console.log of the newProject var

Comment: @Wendigo this error is likely caused by something in your tool chain (`babylon`, which is throwing the error, is a JS parser that used to be used by Babel), perhaps a linter (syntax checker). It's not thrown by Node.js itself.

Comment: @Wendigo I think @robertklep is right. It is being thrown by `babylon` module. probably you should try using babel to transpile your code and see how it responds to the same. It should work without issues if you use `babel-env` preset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed by installing transform-object-rest-spread (https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread).

You can install with `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`.

Then you need to add in the .babelrc:

```
  "plugins": [["transform-object-rest-spread", { "useBuiltIns": true }]]
```

This will do the magic.

This happens because spread operator for objects is still in stage3 of approval on ecmascript.

Hope it can help someone!

Comment: Object spread is finished (stage 4) and in the spec already, right? See https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-object-initializer I think robertklep is right, the issue is not with Node itself, but with something else failing to understand object spread