# object property is not getting deleted even after using delete operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an array of objects. And i want to delete one key named as `id` from it.
I have used the following code to delete it from the object.

```
this.state.result.forEach(item => delete item.id);
```

But still, id is not getting deleted from it. I am not sure why and what's the issue with my code. I have tried to delete several other keys from same object by using the above logic and it worked fine. Only issue i am facing is with `id`.

I think this object property is non-configurable. If so, then how can we delete it.

Can someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using react? Apparently you are trying to mutate the state directly which is not how you update the state in react.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `id` is `non-configurable`, then you cannot delete it.
[See this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_delete). Note that a `TypeError` is thrown in strict mode only.

Answer (score 0):

In React.js you should never try to mutate the state directly. Check out [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) article from the official docs. You have to use setState() to achieve the results. The id isn't being deleted because re-rendering isn't happening.

From the docs,

> Do not modify the state directly

```
// Wrong
this.state.comment = 'Hello';
```

> Instead, use setState():

```
// Correct
this.setState({comment: 'Hello'});
```

Comment: I tried same approach. Still id is not getting deleted. I have even tried to store the state variable in a local variable and delete id from there. But still same issue.

Comment: Please consider creating a reproducible code example as pointed out by a user, it will help in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

In React, you can't directly update the `state`. You always have to do it using `setState` method.

So try this.

```
this.setState({
 result: this.state.result.map(item => {
  let tmpItem = {...item};
  delete tmpItem.id;
  return {...tmpItem}; 
 })
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**

> If you are using the react then you should always use setState for
> changing the state.

**

To explain @Prabu answer

```
    this.setState({ // calling setState for updating the state
       result: this.state.result.map(item => {
           let tmpItem = {...item};// storing all the value here in tmpItem
           delete tmpItem.id; // deleting the key
           return {...tmpItem}; // returning here
       })
    }, ()=> {
        // for immediatly accessing the state you can use callback
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never rely on `state`:s value when calculating the next state as it may be updated asynchronously by React behind the scenes.

Also, try avoiding `delete` as it's a performance killer.

So try this instead:

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  result: state.result.map(({id, ...propsToKeep}) => propsToKeep)
}));
```

or if you have to use `delete`:

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  result: state.result.map(res => { 
    delete res.id; 
    return res; 
  });
}));
```

Comment: Spread operator is not working for me. It is giving unexpected token error. I have already installed it by following: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread. Still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I have referred to several answers on stackoverflow, including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003497/nodejs-problem-with-spread-operators-unexprected-token. But nothing is helping.

Comment: can we use some other solution other than using spread operator for resolving my issue??

Comment: Still it is not deleting the id !! id seems to be non-configurable here..