# Three dots (...) error in postcss-icss-parser.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, postcss

I do `npm build` and after im get error:

```
ERROR in .../PublishingFilter.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/shared/publishingFilter/PublishingFilter.css)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    .../node_modules/css-loader/dist/plugins/postcss-icss-parser.js:34
          accumulator[normalizedUrl] = { ...accumulator[normalizedUrl],
```

node v6.17.1

npm  v3.10.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution**
If you cant upgrade your node version to 8, you just need 
set the version strictly before **3.3.1** of `css-loader`.

```
{
  "css-loader": "3.3.0",
}
```

**Problem**
Three dots is a spread operator from es6 which is supported by Node from v8.3. ([Node v6 failing on object spread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066731/node-v6-failing-on-object-spread))

**Сause**
`ccs-loader` broke backward compatibility of node versions in patch release **3.3.1** on December 10
releases - https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/releases
problem commit - https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/pull/1014/files

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade your node version to 8 and check.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/1019